# Seeing who viewed your profile w/ bonus feature - they can unlock if they retweet about the website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

so I've created a web app that has user profiles, where users can search for fellow users based on interests etc.. How can I provide users with the ability to see who viewed their profile, which isa bonus feature that they can unlock if they retweet about the website.

The which users viewed your profile can be done with something like this I guess:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_visits
  has_many :visitors, :through => :user_visits, :source => :visitor
end

class UserVisit < ActiveRecord::Base
  # user_id :integer
  # visitor_id :integer
  # visited_at :datetime

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :visitor, :foreign_key => 'visitor_id', :class_name => 'User'
end


User.first.visitors = [user_1, user2]
```

Although, I'm not quite sure how they'd be added to the visitors array? I.e. If they visit the page what will cause them to be stored as a visitor?

And the second feature how can I create the ability to un-lock a feature, and how can I make it so the feature will be un-locked if the user tweets a certain message, in this case the website URL.

Comment: For your second feature, you could have a boolean flag in your user. So then in the controller of the page where they can see their visitors you do a before filter that only users with the flag as true can enter there.

To activate the flag, you will need to call the Twitter API. You can do that with a gem like https://github.com/sferik/twitter

Comment: And to count the visitors, it would depend on what you want, but in the action of the controller where you show the user profile, if the visitor is logued in, and is not the same user as the one in the profile, then you add it to the visitors (in the same action).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **User Visits**

> Although, I'm not quite sure how they'd be added to the visitors
>   array? I.e. If they visit the page what will cause them to be stored
>   as a visitor?

To do this, you'd need 3 things:

1. A way to track the user
2. A way to track the visitor
3. A way to keep the record

---

**Track User**

I don't know how your application is set up, but if you're visiting someone's profile, you'd typically have this route:

```
`/users/13`
```

This will give you the `params[:id]` as the `user_id`

---

**Track Visitor**

If the visitor has to be signed in, you should have some sort of session variable defined for them. A typical case would be Devise's `current_user` object, which will allow you to use `current_user.id` as the `visitor_id`

I would then use a `before_filter` function on your `users_controller` to create a record of the visit, like this:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb

before_filter :add_visit

private 
def add_visit
    UserVisit.create(:user_id => params[:id], :visitor_id => current_user.id) if current_user.id
end
```

---

**Store The Record**

To store this information, I'd make a model called UserVisitor, which will have these columns:

```
user_visitors
id | user_id | visitor_id | created_at | updated_at
```

This will allow you to store as many visitors as you wish without encumbering the application structure as a whole

---

### **Retweets**

> And the second feature how can I create the ability to un-lock a
>   feature, and how can I make it so the feature will be un-locked if the
>   user tweets a certain message, in this case the website URL

Further to Roberto's comments, you'd use a standard `boolean` column in your db. I'd recommend putting in your `users` table, and call it `retweet`, like this:

```
add_column :users, :retweet, :boolean
```

What you'd do is keep the `UserVisit` functionality in the backend (for everyone), but on the front-end, you could use the [`cancan` gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) ([Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)) to determine whether the users will have the chance to see who's viewed their profile

As Roberto mentioned, you could handle the retweet boolean inside the "retweet" function. Instead of using Twitter's HTTP-based functionality, you could use their API & create a method to fire after they use the retweet functionality

As soon as the retweet happens, you'll be able to set the boolean to `true`, unlocking the feature